# Why is Perl saying I only use this once? Why is that even an issue?

Tags: perl

I have some code that I've managed to narrow down to the following smallest-code sample.

First I have a module `plugh.pm` which is responsible for reading in a configuration file. The meat of this can basically be replaced with the following, which sets up one configuration item:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub cfgRead () { $main::cfg{"abc"} = "/usr"; }
1;
```

Then I have a main program which uses that module as follows, simply calling the function to set up configuration items, then using one of those items in a subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.005;

require File::Basename;
import File::Basename "dirname";
push (@INC, dirname ($0));
require plugh;

my (%cfg);

sub subOne () {
        my $list = `ls -1 $main::cfg{"abc"}`;
        my @list = split (/\s+/, $list);
        my $fspec;
        foreach $fspec (@list) {
                print $fspec . "\n";
        }
}

sub mainLine () {
        cfgRead();
        subOne();
}

mainLine();
```

Now, when I run this, I get the following output with the first line being standard error and the rest being standard output:

```
Name "main::cfg" used only once: possible typo at /home/xyzzy/bin/xyzzy line 15.
bin
games
include
lib
lib64
local
sbin
share
src
```

The line it's complaining about is the `ls -1` subprocess creation. My question is simply: so what? Yes, I only use it once but why is that even an issue?

If I was *never* using it, then fine, but I can't see why Perl is warning me about only using it once.

I get the variable from the associative array and then use it to get a directory listing. Is there some sort of bizarre Perl guideline that states variables have to be used at least twice? Seven times? Forty-two? I'm seriously stumped.

Comment: Why are you using a global to pass on the `%cfg` data? Why not return the data instead, and use `my %cfg = cfgRead();`?

Comment: @TLP, mainly because it's a pain to pass it to the functions that need access to it in the other module :-) But I'll probably end up going for that since it's better encapsulated (or more likely, passing the individual config items as needed).

Comment: `perl -Mdiagnostics -e '$used_only_once=1'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few odd things here.

First: when you have `use strict` active, you will get a warning if you use a variable without declaring it, **or** referencing it by fully qualified name.

What you have actually done is to declare a local `%cfg` with `my()` in `xyzzy.pl`, and then to reference a **different**, package-global variable `%main::cfg` (implicitly declared by using its fully qualified name).

To make the reference link to the same `%cfg` that you declared, you should declare it `our()` to make it package-global. Then you can either reference it as `$main::cfg{}` in both places (or just `$cfg{}` from `xyzzy.pl`), or else you can declare it `our()` in `plugh.pm` as well (so that you can use the bare %cfg in both places).

The odd thing is that you do have two references to that variable, so you shouldn't get the warning. I think what has happened here is that the implicit declarations in two separate files are assumed to be separate variables.

xyzzy.pl:

```
require plugh;

our (%cfg);

sub subOne () {
   my $list = `ls -1 $cfg{"abc"}`;
   ...
}
```

plugh.pm:

```
our(%cfg);
sub cfgRead () { $cfg{"abc"} = "/usr"; }
```

Comment: I think this may be it though I need to do some more investigation. If I change `my (%cfg);` to `$main::cfg = ();` the warning disappears and everything else still works.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - but it's equivalent to using `our()`. A fully qualified variable name is assumed to be package-global. And in my opinion implicit declaration by fully qualifying is not really in the spirit of `use strict`.

Answer (score 12):

I think your original question is answered, so I'll just pass along my advice. Don't ever use globals if you can avoid it. You are using subroutines as mere clusters of code and not passing them any arguments, and that's where your problems come from.

**Module:**

```
sub cfgRead {
    my %cfg;
    $cfg{"abc"} = "/usr";
    ...
    return \%cfg;
}
```

---

**Main:**

```
sub subOne {
    my $cfg = shift;
    my $list = `ls -1 $cfg->{"abc"}`;
    ....
}

my $cfg = cfgRead();
subOne($cfg);
```

Comment: +1 for this since it's the way I'll eventually be going, with proper encapsulation.

Answer (score 7):

It's simply a helpful comment, because it's pretty unusual to store data in something but never look in it again.  Lets look at a more helpful example instead:

```
use warnings;
$something = 1;
$something = $something + 1;
```

That, of course, works great as you'd expect.  But consider a mistake:

```
use warnings;
$something = 1;
$something = $somehting + 1;
```

If you didn't look closely you wouldn't notice the spelling mistake and probably wouldn't figure out why the final value was wrong (since `$somehting` would be effectively 0).

In this case the warning:

```
Name "main::somehting" used only once: possible typo at tmp.pl line 3.
```

Is much more useful.  It shows you a possible typo.

(`use strict;` would be even better in here, of course)

Comment: Wes, the only problem with this answer is that it was far more subtle than thought. It wasn't a matter of misspelling the variable as you posited, the one I set in the other module was spelt _identically_ to the one I used. It turns out that Russell had it right: though spelt the same, the referred to different things.

Comment: Actually, I realized the `my` was a problem and meant to throw that in there as well.  But your question wasn't "why isn't the code working like I thought it would" it was "My question is simply: so what? Yes, I only use it once but why is that even an issue?".  And actually, if I were you, I wouldn't write the code to reference `$main::anything`.  You should write it such that you pass \%cfg into the function in the module or something, and use the reference.  In the end it'll be better code and will isolate the module from the usage better.